# Convert while loop to an equivalent for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, while-loop

Here is the code which have while loop and i want the help to get thos code converted in the equivalent for loop

```
 #include<stdio.h>
    void main()
    {
        int x = 1;
        int y;
        while(x<=10)
        {
            y=x*x;
            cout<<x<<endl<<y;
            x = x+3;
            getch()
        }
```

Comment: Did you try something? What is your suggestion?

Comment: I am a beginner and really feeling difficulty in making it work.

Comment: So post what you have got so far. (And don't look too much at the answers below, as they are not quite right)

Comment: You should try to solve it by yourself, if you want to overcome your 'beginner'
if you really struck, try post what your progress

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int y;

    for (int x = 1; x <= 10; x += 3)
    {
        y = x * x;
        cout << x << endl << y;
        getch();
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't QUITE do the same thing, does it?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
int x=1;
int y;
for(x; x<=10;x=x+3)
{
y=x*x;
cout<<x<<end1<<y;
getch()
}
```

Something like this?
You can find more information on flow control such as loops etc. here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/

Answer (score 0):

To help you into the right direction.

```
for (int x = 1; stop condition; x += 3)
{
    doStuff();
}
```

Furthermore, I dislike variable names as x since they do not explain their meaning.